# Remove NA values with a group

Tags: r, group-by, na

Here is my example:

```
mydf <- data.frame('col_1'=c('A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D'), 'col_2'=c(100,NA,90,30,50,60,10,NA))

      col_1 col_2
  1     A   100
  2     A    NA
  3     B    90
  4     B    30
  5     C    50
  6     C    60
  7     D    10
  8     D    NA
```

I would like to remove the NA values, grouped by `col_1`, to produce the result below.

```
      col_1 col_2
  1     B    90
  2     B    30
  3     C    50
  4     C    60
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You should include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'col_1' and then `filter` the 'col_2' that have no 'NA's

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   group_by(col_1) %>%
   filter(!any(is.na(col_2)))
```

---

Or do this with `all`

```
mydf %>%
   group_by(col_1) %>%
   filter(all(!is.na(col_2)))
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R`

```
subset(mydf, col_1 %in% names(which(!rowsum(+(is.na(col_2)),
              group = col_1)[,1])))
```

Comment: A little simpler base R: `mydf[ave(is.na(mydf$col_2), mydf$col_1, FUN=any),]`, though `ave` is slow in larger datasets.